# Layer control with mbtiles-php using leaflet wax

Tags: javascript, php, tilemill, mbtiles

I'm trying to get a layer control working that will not only change the tilejson map layers, but also select the appropriate layer interaction (mouse-over) for the selected layer. I'm using the infostraems mbtiles-php code to serve mbtile maps from TillMill on my webserver. I've successfully got the code to initiate the map, and a layer control with the layers I want to show on the map. When I select the layers in the layer control box it will change the map to that layer, however the mouse-over tooltip window only shows information for the original layer - not the new selected layer. I'm sure there is probably a simple solution to this, but I'm a noob with js and can't seem to figure it out. The example map and code can be seen [here](http://humboldtcartography.com/projects/sage/world_languages).

Comment: This is using Wax, which is very deprecated: we'd highly recommend using [a recent version of Mapbox.js](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js) so this is answerable.

Comment: The infostreams mbtiles-php script unfortunately does not use the Mapbox.js, or I can't figure out how to implement it. Being that wax is deprecated I would prefer to use the Mapbox.js, or a similar php server script for serving mbtiles on a webserver utilizing the Mapbox.js.